# How do I use nonfree opencv Libraries in ROS

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I need to use a SURF feature detector in ros. I succeded when I used it outside ROS, but when i try to make a code for a node in ROS, the compiler shows me this:

```
CMakeFiles/stream_node.dir/src/stream_node.cpp.o: In function    `ImageConverter::imageCb(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)':stream_node.cpp:  (.text._ZN14ImageConverter7imageCbERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN11sensor_msgs6Image_ISaIvEEEEE[_ZN14ImageConverter7imageCbERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN11sensor_msgs6Image_ISaIvEEEEE]+0x134): undefined reference to `cv::SURF::SURF(double, int, int, bool, bool)'
 CMakeFiles/stream_node.dir/src/stream_node.cpp.o: In function `cv::SURF::~SURF()':
 stream_node.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev[_ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev]+0xe): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::SURF'
 stream_node.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev[_ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev]+0x26): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::SURF'
 stream_node.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev[_ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev]+0x2e): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::SURF'
 stream_node.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev[_ZN2cv4SURFD1Ev]+0x3b): undefined reference to `VTT for cv::SURF'
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I understand it is because SURF is ubicated in a nonfree library of opencv, then, my includes are:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
```

However, It still doesnt work. Somebody knows what I have to do? Maybe editing the CMakeList.txt?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210696/how-do-i-use-nonfree-opencv-libraries-in-ros/) by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2015-06-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this is answered here:

http://answers.ros.org/question/191380/opencv-surf-is-there-but-cant-be-found/

http://answers.ros.org/question/54026/add-external-opencv-libraries-to-ros-package/

---

Originally posted by [daenny](https://answers.ros.org/users/3203/daenny/) with karma: 376 on 2015-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on 2015-06-10**:
Thanks! I have seen the link where he installs Opencv without OpenCL, but I dont think that would work. But it did!
If someone relates that problem the solution is, in the installlation of openCV, install it this way:
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D WITH_OPENCL=OFF -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/